# How to display a leaderboard of variables JS

Tags: javascript, variables, leaderboard

so I made variables with the value 0 and whenever an event is triggered it adds 1 to the variable, I was wondering if theres any way to show a leaderboard of the variables in order (from biggest to smallest), If you know a way please let me know and I appreciate it in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really sort variables as they are separate objects.  You would need to gather them into a collection and sort that or store your variables in a collection to begin with - a Map object is the most likely candidate for that.  Here's an example of what you could do with an array:

```js
    let a = 100;
    let b = 5;
    let c = 75;
    let d = 6;
    let e = 23;

    let arr = [];
    arr.push({variable: "a", value:a});
    arr.push({variable: "b", value:b});
    arr.push({variable: "c", value:c});
    arr.push({variable: "d", value:d});
    arr.push({variable: "e", value:e});

    arr.sort(function(a, b) {return a.value - b.value});

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      console.log(arr[i].variable + ": " + arr[i].value);
    }
```

Comment: np, if you want them in descending order change, `arr.sort(function(a, b) {return a.value - b.value});` to `arr.sort(function(a, b) {return b.value - a.value});`

Comment: wow sorry for late response but tysm i was wondering how to do this. Lol well thanks alot again it really helps me out!